# Aspnet core Identity Auth with firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, asp.net-core

I tried this code for authentication token with firebase and work ok. There is possibility to maintain this for API and the classic Identity for the normal controller? if I add this code the classic identity does not work.

```
services
                .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.Authority = "xxx";
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = "xxx",
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = "xxx",
                        ValidateLifetime = true
                    };
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

I use .NET Core 3.0 as an example.

Install packages (NuGet): `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer`

Update your Controllers to add [Authorize] attribute to your class or method.

Update the Startup class with the following add-ons.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services
        .AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddJwtBearer(options =>
        {
            options.Authority = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-project-id";
            options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "https://securetoken.google.com/my-project-id",
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "my-project-id",
                ValidateLifetime = true
            };
        });
      services.AddControllers();
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseRouting();
    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();
    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapControllers();
    });
 }
```

Make the test again on your API, you should have a nice 401 error (unauthorized).

In order to test the API we need a valid token generated by Firebase. The easiest way to do this is use Firebase REST API thanks to the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/auth/).

To do a log-in with email/password (the ones we created manually before), the URL for the POST request is [https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=[API_KEY]](https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=%5BAPI_KEY%5D) and here is an example of request body (obviously change the email and password).

```
{
  "email": "myemail@address.changeme",
  "password": "mysecretpassword",
  "returnSecureToken": "true"
}
```

You should have a successful reply, assuming you provided with a valid token (limited in time) in the idToken field.

```
{
  "kind": "identitytoolkit#VerifyPasswordResponse",
  "localId": "****",
  "email": "****",
  "displayName": "",
  "idToken": "****",
  "registered": true,
  "refreshToken": "****",
  "expiresIn": "3600"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however it is out of date. Is there any chance you could update this for .NET 6, please?